# How to Invoke and use WSAAsyncSelect() in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback

I edited my question when I set the bounty.
I want to Invoke/DllImport WSAAsyncSelect() from WinAPI and use it much like I use it in Delphi/C++

For example - Delphi

```
//Async CallBack handler Declaration
procedure MessageHandler(var Msg:Tmessage);Message WM_WINSOCK_ASYNC_MSG;

//Where i setup the Async
dwError := WSAAsyncSelect(Sock, form1.handle, WM_WINSOCK_ASYNC_MSG, FD_CLOSE or FD_READ);

//Async Callback Handler
procedure Tform1.MessageHandler(var Msg:Tmessage);
begin
  case WSAGetSelectEvent(MSG.LParam) of //LParam is FD_READ/FR_CLOSE/FD_WRITE
    FD_READ: OnSocketRead(MSG.WParam); //WPARAM is the Socket itself.
    FD_CLOSE: OnSocketClose(MSG.WParam);
  end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not as easy to interact with low level APIs in .Net as it is in unmanaged C++. You'll get no argument about that. You're probably trying to apply the wrong solution to your problem. It's not an answer to your question, but look in the framework, the functionality may be there at a higher level.

Comment: Maybe tell us what you want to **do** (i.e. what is the desired behaviour), rather than **how** you are trying to do it (WSAAsyncSelect) - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Its much more simple to use that api instead BeginRecv.The problem is that I receive the next packet before I finished the work with the current.Meaning When I'm done with the current received packet(which takes some time) the next packet is lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it! Finaly!!!

WSAAsyncSelect() structure

```
    [DllImport("wsock32.dll")]
    public static extern int WSAAsyncSelect(
    int socket,
    int hWnd,
    int wMsg,
    int lEvent
    );
```

WS2 Class

```
public class WS2
{
    public static Socket sock;
    public static byte[] data = new byte[8096];
    public static int server = 0;
    public static bool forced = true;

    public static void Close()
    {
        //Extern.closesocket(sock.Handle.ToInt32());
        //Extern.WSACleanup();

        sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sock.Close();

        if (forced)
        {
            Connect();
        }
    }
    public static void ConnectTo(string ip,int port)
    {
        sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sock.Connect(ip, port);

        int handle = 0;
        var form1 = Form.ActiveForm as FormMain;
        if (form1 != null)
            handle = form1.GetHandle;
        if (handle == 0)
        {
            FormMain.PerformActionOnMainForm(form => form.memo.Text += "An error occured: Error code WS_01_ASYNC_HANDLE");
            return;
        }
        Extern.WSAAsyncSelect(sock.Handle.ToInt32(), handle, Values.MESSAGE_ASYNC, Values.FD_READ | Values.FD_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void Connect()
    {
        //Get IP && port
        string ip = GetIPFromHost("gwgt1.joymax.com");
        if (ip == "")
        {
            ip = GetIPFromHost("gwgt2.joymax.com");
            if (ip == "")
            {
            }
            server +=2;
        }
        else
            server +=1;

        int port = 15779;

        //
        ConnectTo(ip, port);
    }

    public static void Receive()
    {
        int size = sock.Receive(data);
        if (size == 0)
        {
            FormMain.PerformActionOnMainForm(form => form.memo.Text += "An error occured: Error Code WS_02_RECV_BEGN");
        }

        Main.Handle(data, size);
    }

    public static string GetIPFromHost(string HostName)
    {
        IPHostEntry ip;
        try
        {
            ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(HostName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
        return ip.AddressList[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

WndProc in the Form class.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == Values.MESSAGE_ASYNC)
        {

            switch (m.LParam.ToInt32())
            {
                case Values.FD_READ:
                    WS2.Receive();
                    break;
                case Values.FD_WRITE: break;
                case Values.FD_CLOSE:
                    WS2.Close();
                    break;
                default: break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Get Handle:

```
    public int GetHandle
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                return (int)this.Invoke((GetHandleDelegate)delegate
                {
                    return this.Handle.ToInt32();
                });
            }
            return this.Handle.ToInt32();
        }
    }
    private delegate int GetHandleDelegate();
```

Comment: Very nice. This would solve a huge problem with the C# .NET Framwork: There is no way to enqueue an asynchronous socket read for completion on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

(edit: relates mainly to the original question, before it was edited and a bounty added)

I've been looking at this problem recently - see [Async without the pain](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/async-without-pain.html). Note the comment at the end about using the delegate version - this simplifies the calling slightly.

As an update, the final code would look something like below, and as it transpires is very similar to what F# uses under the bonnet:

```
public static void RunAsync<T>(
    Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> begin,
    Func<IAsyncResult, T> end,
    Action<Func<T>> callback) {
    begin(ar => {
        T result;
        try {
            result = end(ar); // ensure end called
            callback(() => result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            callback(() => { throw ex; });
        }
    }, null);
}
```