# How can i get messages in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, winsock, message

How can I get a specific message on a specific method?

I've seen some examples and people use "ref" ,but I dont understand it.

In delphi,for example,my function(method) must be declared in the Main Form class and next to the declaration I have to put the message

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  protected
    procedure MessageHandler(var Msg:Tmessage);Message WM_WINSOCK_ASYNC_MSG;
end;
```

I need this in C# so I can use WSAAsyncSelect in my application

Check [>my other Question<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686355/how-to-invoke-and-use-wsaasyncselect-in-c) with bounty 550 reputation to understand what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET winforms, all messages go to `WndProc`, so you can override that:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_WINSOCK_ASYNC_MSG)
        {
            // invoke your method
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

If I have misunderstood, please say - but I think you would do well to avoid this low-level approach, and describe what you want to *achieve* - i.e. it might be that `.Invoke`/`.BeginInvoke` are more appropriate.

Comment: Using BeginRecv EndRecv I sometimes miss packets or the delay is too big.I can't get used it.I really want WSAAsyncSelect.I gave all my reputation here for it in my bounted question. \n\n As for your answer here - How do I add WndProc? I don't have in my application

Comment: Assuming you have a form, you just type (in the .cs) "protected override void WndProc..."

Comment: Ok thanks,I'll create another question about how to get the Handle.Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can override the [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(vs.71).aspx) method on a control (e.g. form).

WndProc takes a reference to a message object. A ref parameter in C# is akin to a var parameter in Delphi. The message object has a Msg property that contains the message type, e.g (from MSDN):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
{
    // Listen for operating system messages.
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        // The WM_ACTIVATEAPP message occurs when the application
        // becomes the active application or becomes inactive.
        case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:

            // The WParam value identifies what is occurring.
            appActive = (((int)m.WParam != 0));

            // Invalidate to get new text painted.
            this.Invalidate();

            break;                
    }        
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```